# Injection Token in Angular for Cesium.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cesiumjs

I'm trying to use the cesium.js library the angular way so that I can still code in typescript, I have seen some 3rd party lib tutorials, and I'm trying to inject the dependency with a dependencty token. right now, my code is not compiling, and I'm getting the error:

```
ERROR in ....../node_modules/cesium/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js (557,23102): Unreachable code detected.
ERROR in ....../node_modules/cesium/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js (557,24518): Unreachable code detected.
ERROR in ....../node_modules/cesium/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js (559,26990): Unreachable code detected.
```

I have a stack blitz with all the necessary code, but stack blitz can't handle all the dependencies to run and get the above error, so feel free to copy the code into your own environment.

[my stack blitz 'demo'](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cesium-integration?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) and [here is the tutorial I followed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-CHs1qWGNBQ)

here are the raw files for reference as well.

This project is build with **angular-cli**

I started by running `npm install --save cesium`

cesium.lib.ts

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import * as cesiumLib from '../../../node_modules/cesium/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js';

export const cesiumToken = new InjectionToken('cesium');
export const cesium = cesiumLib;
export type Cesium = typeof cesiumLib;
export * from 'cesium';
```

gobe.module.ts

```
import { GlobeComponent } from './globe.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import * as cesiumLib from './cesium.lib';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    GlobeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: cesiumLib.cesiumToken, useValue: cesiumLib.cesium}
  ]
})

export class GlobeModule {}
```

globe.component.ts

```
import { cesium, cesiumToken } from './cesium.lib';
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-globe',
    templateUrl: './globe.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./globe.component.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class GlobeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    constructor( @Inject(cesiumToken) private cesium: any) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.viewer = new Cesium.viewer('cesiumContainer')
    }

}
```

globe.component.html

```
<div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
```

globe.component.css

```
@import url(../Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css);

#cesiumContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 720px;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",

    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

.angular-cli.json snippet

```
"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap-switch/dist/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.min.css",
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "../node_modules/cesium/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
          "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "../node_modules/bootstrap-switch/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js",
          "../node_modules/cesium/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"
```

___**UPDATE**______

after making changes from @Justin Shwartzenberger

the compiler is successful but the page loads continuously until if fails... ideas? this occurs once I add the script and css to the .angular-cli.json file

Comment: could you please provide your tsconfig.json file as well?  Also, is this an Angular CLI project, or what seed project is this from?

Comment: hey @JoeSkeen I made the changed and updated the question

Answer (score 0):

In the `.angular-cli.json` file under the `apps` array first object add:
*(to bring in the 3rd party css and js files needed)*

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../node_modules/cesium/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/cesium/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"
],
```

In your `cesium.lib.ts` file just have:
*(to create the `InjectionToken` only, everything else is global from that `Cesium` lib as it doesn't appear to be able to be imported)*

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
export const cesiumToken = new InjectionToken('cesium');
```

In your `typings.d.ts` add:
*(so TypeScript knows about the Cesium thing)*

```
declare var Cesium: any;
```

In your `app.module.ts` set up:
*(only need to bring in the token and then set its value to the Cesium global that the 3rd party lib creates)*

```
import {cesiumToken} from './cesium.lib';

. . .

providers: [
  { provide: cesiumToken, useValue: Cesium }
],

. . .
```

And finally, in your `app.component.ts`:
*(just need to get that token value injected into a class field and then use the API of it from there)*

```
. . .

constructor( @Inject(cesiumToken) private cesium: any) {}

. . .

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.viewer = new this.cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
}

. . .
```

You can go further with creating typings for the Cesium lib and encapsulating more from here, but this should get you up and working.

Comment: Shwartzenberger  I followed exactly, and Angular compiles, but the page fails to load. I created a new seed project, and tried to implement this in the simple seed application, and the same thing occured. Angular compiles, I visit local host, it loads forever, then it says 'aw snap your page could not be loaded'